# Angular 12, how to display the login button when the user is not signed in, and the user's avatar is displayed when the user is signed in

Tags: angular, angular-material

```js
header.component.html
  <div *ngIf="show; then True; else False"></div>
  <ng-template #True>
    <div>
      Not signed in
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #False>
    <div>
      User avatar
    </div>
  </ng-template>

header.component.ts
  show: boolean = true;

  avatar: string = '';

  me() {
    this.meService.get().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.show = true;
        if (response.body?.avatar === "") {
          this.avatar = "src/assets/user-solid.svg";
        } else {
          this.avatar = `${config.avatar}${response.body?.avatar}`;
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

In the official of angular, search for `ng-template` and no examples were found.

What should be done to make `show` be `false` when the user is signed in?

GitHub: https://github.com/teaoea/teaoea.com/tree/main/src/app/ui/header

Comment: What `meService` is doing?
You can check this about `ng-template`: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Comment: `meService`: get user information

Comment: Can you share parts where you do the sign-in?

Comment: [https://github.com/teaoea/teaoea.com/tree/main/src/app/user/signin](https://github.com/teaoea/teaoea.com/tree/main/src/app/user/signin)

Answer (score 0):

In your `SigninService` service try adding these lines:

```
export class SigninService {

  private isSignedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  onSignedIn$ = this.isSignedIn.asObservable();
```

then in `post` method emit true/false depending on success of the sign-in:

```
  post(signin: Signin) {
    return this.http.post<any>(urls.user.signin, signin, options).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        localStorage.setItem('Authorization', response.body?.message);
        this.router.navigate(['/'], {relativeTo: this.route}).then();

        this.isSignedIn.next(true); // <-- success
      },
      (error) => {
        this.isSignedIn.next(false); // <-- unsuccessful
        if (error.status === 404) {
          this.snackBar.open('mistake username');
          return;
        } else if (error.status === 403) {
          this.snackBar.open('mistake password');
          return;
        }
      }
    );
```

In your `HeaderComponent` inject this service

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private meService: MeService, 
    private signInService: SigninService // <-- service
  ) {
```

and subscribe to signIn events:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signInService.onSignedIn$.subscribe((isSignedIn: boolean) => {
      this.showSignInButtons = !isSignedIn;
    });
  }
```

I renamed `show` to `showSignInButtons` for better readability.

```
<div *ngIf="showSignInButtons; then isSignin; else me"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wish that if the user is not signed in, the sign in and sign up  button will be displayed, but the user has signed in, the user avatar will be displayed

Comment: Thanks,`ngOnInit(): void {
    this.me();
  }`